# IndexError: Error shows up when trying to loop over a python list

Tags: python

I was making a quiz app with python (and bullet module), so I am facing the following problem...

I am trying to loop over a list and create object of a class by generating random number from 0 to len(list)+1, for the index. It throws IndexError:

Code: `questionlist.py`

```py
from question import Question
from random import randint

# Question(text, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer)

texts = [
 "Which website is mostly used to search for errors in a piece of code (or anything related to software engineering)?",
 "Which of the following companies has developed and is maintaining React JS?",
 "What is 'M' in MERN Stack?",
 "Which of the following is 'not' a programming language?",
 "Which of the following is 'not' used for Machine Learning"
]

option1_s = [
 "Reddit",
 "Google",
 "MariaDB",
 "Redis",
 "Keras",
]

option2_s = [
 "Stackoverflow",
 "Mozilla"
 "MongoDB",
 "Java",
 "Tensorflow",
]

option3_s = [
 "Stackexchange",
 "Twitter",
 "MySQL",
 "Python",
 "PyTorch"
]

option4_s = [
 "Discord",
 "Facebook",
 "Memcached",
 "Assembly",
 "Postman",
]

answers = [
 "Stackoverflow",
 "Facebook",
 "MongoDB",
 "Redis"
]

def create_question_list(num_of_questions):
 questions = []
 

 for i in range(num_of_questions):
     
     index_number = randint(0, len(texts)+1)
     print(index_number)
     questions.append(
         Question(
             texts[index_number],
             option1_s[index_number],
             option2_s[index_number],
             option3_s[index_number],
             option4_s[index_number],
             answers[index_number]
         )
     )

 return questions
```

Throws

IndexError: list index error out of range

There are 2 more files, but the bug exists in this file, but still if someone feels like to answer, you need to check the other 2 codes also, here they are: https://github.com/codingdsb/Python-Quiz-App/

Please answer as fast as possible

Comment: `answers` is shorter than the other collections, that is the problem.

Comment: Change ```index_number = randint(0, len(texts)+1)``` to ```index_number = randint(0, len(texts)-1)```. And also make ```answers``` the same length as all other lists.

Answer (score 0):

RandInt returns an integer between the two input parameters both included.
List indices in python go from (0 - len(arr)-1) inclusive.
In your code, when you run this line
`index_number = randint(0, len(texts)+1)`
You are intending to get an index of the various lists you have. However, the randint can also return the integers len(texts) and len(texts)+1 which cannot be indexed as the array has not that many elements.
You should replace the second parameter of the randint function to len(texts)-1 so that it randomly returns a value that can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't answer about one thing if u don't put the rest of classes.

The problem is that you have the answer number higher than the lenght of some lists of questions:

link of proyect for run: https://replit.com/@batichico/quiz

you should put `index_number = randint(0, len(texts)-1)` instead of `index_number = randint(0, len(texts)+1)`